SQL Conditional Join When key column has null values
I have a fact table and two dimension tables, I want to join fact with dimension-1 on key1 but if key1 is null then join fact table with dimension-2 on key2.
This is what I am doing so far:
SELECT fact.*, coalesce(dim1.type, dim2.type) as type    
FROM schema.fact_table as fact
LEFT JOIN schema.dimension1 as dim1 
    ON fact.key1 = dim1.key1
LEFT JOIN schema.dimension2 as dim2 
    ON fact.key2 = dim2.key2 AND fact.key1 IS NULL;

I am looking for other ways of doing this as I will be doing inner join in my application.
The condition is if key1 is null then join with dimension2 on key2

Can you add some sample data to your question?  The join strategy looks OK, but rathre than doing an IS NULL check, you should be selectively choosing from one table or the other in the SELECT statement.

Yes I do coalesce from one or other table in select statement.

I don't get this, what's wrong with your current query?

Try an UNION to achieve this

In you query you have a condition "fact.key1 IS NULL" and also a join fact.key1 = dim1.key1 , you can do  something like this in you join where you substitute Null with '-' or any other  NVL(NULLIF(TRIM(fact.key1) , ''),'-')

What you've achieved is fine as per this.
fact.key1 on inner join will exclude records having fact.key1 being NULL.
So, Union with the rest of the records inner joining with fact.key2 and mentioning fact.key1 being NULL.
SELECT fact.*, dim1.type as type    
FROM schema.fact_table as fact
INNER JOIN schema.dimension1 as dim1 
ON fact.key1 = dim1.key1 

UNION ALL

SELECT fact.*, dim2.type as type    
FROM schema.fact_table as fact
INNER JOIN schema.dimension2 as dim2 
ON fact.key2 = dim2.key2 And fact.key1 IS NULL


it feels like that UNION should be a UNION ALL given they cannot overlap, and thus there is nothing to gain from the cost of the UNION

So firstly we need some "fake data" or otherwise it can be almost meaningless to compare SQL, as the results could be 100% the same but also 200% slower.
so lets make 10K of each dimension, and 10M facts:
create or replace table dimension1 as
    select seq8() as key1, seq1() as type
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>10000));

create or replace table dimension2 as
    select seq8() as key2, seq1() as type
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>10000));

create or replace table fact_table as 
    select 
        seq8() as f_id,
        iff(random() > 0, seq8() % 10000, null) as key1,
        seq8()% 10000 as key2
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>10000000));

and time your existing code:
SELECT fact.*, coalesce(dim1.type, dim2.type) as type    
FROM fact_table as fact
LEFT JOIN dimension1 as dim1 
    ON fact.key1 = dim1.key1
LEFT JOIN dimension2 as dim2 
    ON fact.key2 = dim2.key2 AND fact.key1 IS NULL;

I had to make the tables bigger to make it slow, and still these do not feel meaningful enough:
-- 100K Fact rows 827ms
-- 1M Fact rows 1.6s
-- 10M Fact rows 5.4s

so spliting those into two reads, (this allows for dimensions to be missing, albeit, then the result of the colesce is not equal to below):
SELECT fact.*, dim1.type as type    
FROM fact_table as fact
LEFT JOIN dimension1 as dim1 
    ON fact.key1 = dim1.key1 
WHERE fact.key1 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT fact.*, dim2.type as type    
FROM fact_table as fact
LEFT JOIN dimension2 as dim2 
    ON fact.key2 = dim2.key2
WHERE fact.key1 IS NULL;

-- 10M facts 4.9s
So Meera's answer:
SELECT fact.*, dim1.type as type    
FROM fact_table as fact
INNER JOIN dimension1 as dim1 
ON fact.key1 = dim1.key1 

UNION

SELECT fact.*, dim2.type as type    
FROM fact_table as fact
INNER JOIN dimension2 as dim2 
ON fact.key2 = dim2.key2 And fact.key1 IS NULL;

-- UNION 3.2s
-- UNION ALL 4.6s

and for this data those give the same results:
select * from table(result_scan('01b541d2-0205-49ec-0005-aae700076206'))
minus 
select * from table(result_scan('01b541d1-0205-4f37-0005-aae7000790ee'));

select * from table(result_scan('01b541d1-0205-4f37-0005-aae7000790ee'))
minus 
select * from table(result_scan('01b541d2-0205-49ec-0005-aae700076206'));

so boosting those tables to 100K and 100M (all done on a X-SMALL WH)



Code
Time




Your
17s


Mine
15s


Meera's Union
20s


Meera's Union AL
16s



so it feels it's all much of a muchness.
